# Adjusting range of predicted values in ggeffects

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggpredict` to plot the marginal effects of temperature (a continuous variable) from a glmm zero-inflated model:

```
pr1 = ggpredict(mod, "temp", type = "re.zi")
```

The function is working properly, but only returns predicted values for 7 random temperatures. Does anyone know how to increase the quantity of x values, to 25 for example?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: See also https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/issues/64#issuecomment-471324641

Answer (score 1):

According to the section **Marginal Effects at Specific Values** of the link https://rdrr.io/github/strengejacke/ggeffects/man/ggpredict.html, the syntax for ggpredict looks something like this:

```
pr1 = ggpredict(mod, terms = "temp", type = "re.zi")
```

You can take a random sample of any size by inserting **sample=n** in square brackets after the name of the temp variable (making sure a white space exists between temp and the sample option), e.g. **terms = "temp [sample=25]"**, which will sample 25 values at random from all possible values of the variable temp:

```
pr1 = ggpredict(mod, terms = "temp [sample=25]", type = "re.zi")
```